# TMG only windows 2008 r2 installing. NOT WORKING windows server 2012 r2

Tags: windows, ddos, flooding, attacks, tmg

TMG Forefront only working windows server 2008 or 2008R2 - Not working windows server 2012.

How to mitigation windows server 2012R2 - Flood attacks,http attacks ?

Please help how to build windows server 2012R2

```
Maximum TCP connect requests per minute per IP address   600 (custom: 6,000)
Maximum concurrent TCP connections per IP address        160 (custom: 400)  
Maximum half-open TCP connections (non-configurable)     80  
Maximum HTTP requests per minute per IP address          600 (custom: 6,000)  
Maximum new non-TCP sessions per minute per rule         1,000  
Maximum concurrent UDP sessions per IP address           160 (custom: 400)  
Specify how many denied packets trigger an alert         600
```

Thank you for help (all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TMG Forefront is EOL. Please use another product, or use the builtin tool of Windows Server.

Support for Windows 2012 in TMG was never finished, as feature like IPv6 was not supported in TMG.

> 3.We are discontinuing any further releases of the following Forefront-branded solutions: 
>   - Forefront Protection 2010 for Exchange
>   Server (FPE) 
>   - Forefront Protection 2010 for SharePoint (FPSP)
>   - Forefront Security for Office Communications Server (FSOCS)
>   - Forefront Threat Management Gateway 2010 (TMG)
>   - Forefront Threat
>   - Management Gateway Web Protection Services (TMG WPS)

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloud/2012/09/12/important-changes-to-forefront-product-roadmaps/